# Python int to bytes conversion error with some values

Tags: python

I am using the [int.to_bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#additional-methods-on-integer-types) method within Python to convert integer values into bytes.

With certain values, this seems to fail. Attached is the output from the Python console:

```
value = 2050
value.to_bytes(2, 'big')
>>> b'\x08\x02'
value = 2082
value.to_bytes(2, 'big')
>>> b'\x08"'
```

With a value of `2050`, the conversion seems to be correct. But when the value is `2082`, for some reason only the upper byte seems to be extracted. Any reason as to why this is happening?

Comment: Unfortunately, realized it now...

Comment: But its just the way that `bytes` str and repr are implemented. Its the right values and works. Just put some tape on the monitor so you don't have to see it.

Comment: Haha, would give that a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It extracts all bytes. Try

```
value = 2082
x = value.to_bytes(2, 'big')
print(x[0]) # Output: 8
print(x[1]) # Output: 34
```

When you convert to string, [byte `34` translates to ASCII `"`](https://ascii.cl/), which is what you see.